# While loop wont stop looping with exception

Tags: java, exception, while-loop

probably missing something really silly, but my while loop will not stop printing the error message.

Could someone have a quick look and point me in the right direction?

```
package week5;

import java.util.*;
public class Week5 {       
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);        
        inputInt();        
    }

    public static int inputInt(){        
        Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("Enter number:");        
        int num;                                
        boolean carryOn = true;                       
        while (carryOn = true) {                 
                {                                    
                  try {                       
                      num = myKeyboard.nextInt();                      
                      carryOn = false;                                                                  
                      }                  
                  catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println ("Integers only");                                         
                   }                       
                  }                                                    
          }
        return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Probably the most common error in software development. Thanks for remembering old days ;)

Comment: Try to add return -1 in your cach

Comment: myKeyboard.next(); in the catch solved it, cheers guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
    while (carryOn = true) {
```

Instead of using the comparison operator `==`, you are using the assignment operator `=`. So essentially, you're setting `carryOn` to `true` every iteration, then automatically running the body of the loop since the condition essentially becomes

```
    while (true) {
```

Just change that problem line to

```
    while (carryOn == true) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer although i've tried both solutions yet as soon as I enter anything other than an integer the integers only error prints until I end the program

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the infinite loop and the fact you always `return 0;` no matter what the user types, the code is far more complex than it needs to be.

```
// only create one scanner
private static final Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = inputInt();
    // do something with num
}

public static int inputInt() {
    System.out.println("Enter number:");

    while (true) { 
        if (myKeyboard.hasNextInt()) {
            int num = myKeyboard.nextInt();
            myKeyboard.nextLine(); // discard the rest of the line.
            return num;
        }
        System.out.println ("Integers only, please try again"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
     while(carryOn==true)
```

or

```
     while(carryOn)
```

will solve your problem